# Building GCC: What are the advantages and disadvantages of bootstrap?

Tags: gcc

I understand what bootstrapping a compiler build does, but I don't understand the advantages and disadvantages for regular users.  (I assume there is value for GCC maintainers.)

When configuring GCC, there are two options: `--enable-bootstrap` and `--disable-bootstrap`.  As I understand, for vanilla compiler builds, `--enable-bootstrap` is enabled by default.

I cannot find anything on the advantages and disadvantages of using `--disable-bootstrap`.  My *Google-fu* fails me.  I assume the build will be faster, but what are the downsides?

To be clear, I am doing a vanilla x86-64 Linux GCC build from v6.1.0 official sources.

I ask because I see the option `--disable-bootstrap` used in the Linux from Scratch instructions here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/gcc.html

Comment: Generally if you don't understand what the option does, you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: More people need to read the [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) guide by Johnathan Wakely, a GCC dev, instead of guides from the Internet. For one thing, `./contrib/download_prerequisites` is a step that's ignored in most guides in favor for hand-compiling MPC, etc. *which is highly not recommended*.

Comment: One disadvantage, although slight, is that --enable-bootstrap takes longer to compile. This is why I tend to pass --disable-bootstrap since compiling GCC already takes quite a long time, even if it is a very important program and one might be tempted to want to ensure it is "as correct as possible"..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [GCC configuration documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) says:

> `--disable-bootstrap`
> For a native build, the default configuration is to perform a 3-stage bootstrap of the compiler when ‘make’ is invoked, testing that GCC can compile itself correctly. If you want to disable this process, you can configure with `--disable-bootstrap`.
>
> `--enable-bootstrap`
> In special cases, you may want to perform a 3-stage build even if the target and host triplets are different. This is possible when the host can run code compiled for the target (e.g. host is i686-linux, target is i486-linux). Starting from GCC 4.2, to do this you have to configure explicitly with `--enable-bootstrap`.

**On the whole, you're best off leaving this default well alone.**

If you use `--disable-bootstrap`, it  does a 1-stage build (per [Explorer09](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4606310/explorer09) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473532/building-gcc-what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-bootstrap/37473663?noredirect=1#comment67916578_37473663), but I've *still* not tried it), which could work when a 3-stage build won't.

If you need to know more, read the documentation.

Comment: No. `--disable-bootstrap` only does 1-stage build. The purpose of having a 3-stage build is to ensure GCC can compile itself flawlessly. The first stage would produce "GCC compiled by another compiler (maybe non-GCC)", the second stage would produce "GCC compiled by GCC", the third stage would be testing if this produces identical binary to stage 2. (If yes, discard stage 1 & 2 binaries then.) For cross-compiling GCC, the binary just built may not even run on the "--build" machine, so only 1 stage could be done.

Comment: And I managed to go all of this time without realizing there was a [documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) for the configure script.  Wow, sad. So thank you for that!

Comment: Let's highlight Quintessence **you're best leaving this default well alone.**

Comment: I disagree with that reasoning kyb because there could still be other factors that may be relevant, if defaults are changed. Because then the answer above would also be different, even IF the default values MIGHT make the most sense, that need not necessarily be the case for all possibilities. For example, if you want to bootstrap a LFS from scratch quickly, and time is important, then disabling bootstrap is always better, as opposed to a situation where it may be the default, and then slow down the compilation process. In such a case the generic statement "default is always best" is wrong.